# How can I refer to an absent value in expl3?

Tags: expl3, xparse

The `xparse` package has a concept of `-NoValue-`, a kind of '`\null`' token used to represent the absence of any value (where `\null` would probably be considered a value).

If I would like to manually use this value, how would I go about doing it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\some_test:NTF{\marker}{true}{false} % should print true

\end{document}
```

---

My specific use case is in an `l3prop` list:

```
\prop_new:N \g__ds_type_supertype_subtypes_prop
\prop_put:Nnn \g__ds_type_supertype_subtypes_prop
 { some_type_that_has_no_supertypes }
 { \marker,subtypes,here }
```

with the generalization (note I have not directly tested this yet).

```
% To manage our typing, we will have a property list going from
% supertype -> supertype,subtype,...,subtype
\prop_new:N \g__ds_types_supertype_subtypes_prop
\let\_ds_types_no_supertype\q_no_value
\let\_ds__if_no_supertype_p\quark_if_no_value_p

% Create a new type (#1) that has a supertype (#2)
\cs_new:Npn \_ds_new_type_with_supertype:nn #1 #2
 {
  \clist_new:c
   { g__types__ #1 __supertype_subtypes_clist }

  \clist_put_right:cn
   { g__types__ #1 __supertype_subtypes_clist }
   { #2 }

  \prop_put:Nnn \g__ds_types_supertype_subtypes_prop
   { #1 }
   { \use:c { g__types__ #1 __supertype_subtypes_clist } }
 }

% Create a new type (#1) that has no supertypes
\cs_new:Npn \_ds_new_type:n #1
 {
  \_ds_new_type_with_supertype:nn { #1 } { \_ds_types_no_supertype }
 }
```

Comment: There is no `\NoValue` (at least not any more). I guess you don't want to simply write `-NoValue-` (or you would) but it's rather unclear to me what you actually want...

Comment: What about `\q_no_value` and `\quark_if_no_value:nTF`?

Comment: @cgnieder But that's definitely the better solution when you aren't working on the document level!  I wouldn't mind seeing that as an answer `:-)`

Comment: You said you're going to use it on `\prop_put:Nnn`. That's not a document level. (It seems wrong to me to use such a marker on the document level, anyway. [`\NoValue` has been removed deliberately from `xparse` because people used it in a wrong way.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68752/xparse-novalue-gone-how-to-check-multiple-novalues-now/68753#comment146695_68752)) It is still rather unclear what you need this for...

Comment: @cgnieder As I said, the `quark` solution is much better *for my application* but it isn't strictly what the question was asking. I've seen similar things go down here on TeX.SX so in the spirit of those, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it :-)  I'll edit the question appropriately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10295/discussion-between-cgnieder-and-sean-allred)

Comment: @cgnieder My apologies, I just saw the notification.

Comment: No idea what you are up to, but `\q_no_value` shouldn't really be stored anywhere other than a return `tl`. It's used to represent the fact that something cannot be returned: any data structure should therefore not actually store it but rather use it when asked for something that is not there.

Comment: A few (late) comments.  Instead of `\let` one can use `\cs_set_eq:NN`, or, better here, `\cs_new_eq:NN`.  Also, `\quark_if_no_value_p:` is missing the trailing colon (all expl3 functions have trailing colons), as is the predicate you are defining.  Since your variables are global (rightfully, since types should probably not interact with grouping), you must use global assignments, so `\prop_gput...` and `\clist_gput...`.  This is not detected automatically.  It is hard to comment on the more general approach yet, I will eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\NoValue` marker [has been removed deliberately from `xparse`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68752/xparse-novalue-gone-how-to-check-multiple-novalues-now/68753#comment146695_68752). This makes sense: it defeats the purpose of having *no* value when you have a macro that expands to this none-value.

On the expl3 code level you could use the quark `\q_no_value`, though, and test it with

- `\quark_if_no_value:n(TF)`,
- `\quark_if_no_value_p:n`,
- `\quark_if_no_value:N(TF)` or
- `\quark_if_no_value_p:N`.

If you find yourself on the document level in the need for `\IfNoValueTF{\NoValue}{true}{false}` then I suspect the syntax choices you made are wrong and should be reconsidered.

Comment: Sorry for removing the tick, but I acted too hastily... it appears that I've fallen victim to the warning in the `interface3` documentation of infinite loops---compilation never stops :/ Could you edit in a MWE?

Comment: Then you probably have allowed to expand the quark which may _never_ happen! `\q_no_value` like every other quark contains itself! If it is allowed to expand it will expand endlessly. (This is one of the reasons why I asked you for the _actual_ use case.)

Comment: So I guess my issue boils down to, for the moment: will `q_no_value` be expanded in my use above (the edit)?

Comment: For the record, it was, but all I needed to do was use the `\exp_not:N` function from `l3expan`.  Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is already one [answer from cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129898) explaining that at the code level we have `\q_no_value`, but I think it would be useful to see why we have two apparently similar concepts.

At the document level, users can and do omit values: after all a powerful part of the LaTeX syntax is the idea of optional arguments. To test for presence/absence, we therefore need a marker. However, as at the user level mistakes are likely and it might actually be useful to be able to print this marker, we use a construct which can be printed safely: `-NoValue-`. Underlying how this is done is some category code stuff plus a string-like (`\(pdf)strcmp`) comparison.

At the code level, and around for a lot longer, we have `\q_no_value`, which as mentioned by cgnieder is a 'quark': a macro that expands to itself. Such a macro can therefore *never* be safely expanded in an uncontrolled sense as an infinite loop results (a single expansion is OK as it leaves the quark unchanged). The quark tests were written to be very fast, and pre-date the use of `\(pdf)strcmp` in `expl3`. They also work such that

```
\quark_if_no_value:NTF \q_no_value
```

and

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \q_no_value }
\quark_if_no_value:NTF \l_tmpa_tl
```

give the same result.

Over time the use of quarks has been somewhat refined by the team: `\q_no_value` is essentially designed to be returned by a 'get' function, *e.g.*

```
\prop_get:NnN \l_some_prop { some-key } \l_tmpa_tl
```

when the value is not found in the data structure. In contrast, `-NoValue-` is about something missing at a very different (interface) level.

Comment: Imagine a function `\get_supertype:n` that takes one type and returns its 'parent' type - if there is no parent type, this would be a valid use case, no?

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, but whatever structure you store the types in wouldn't actually contain `\q_no_value`, but would rather return this if no type was found. See for example the implementation of `\prop_get:NnN`.